# Zachariah 13: 6-7 8-9 why aren't 8-9 considered prophetic toward the Holy Trinity?

Tags: prophecy, zechariah, trinity

I read this as prophetic to the existance of the Holy Trinity, Jesus being the earthly embodiment of the Father, Son and Holy Spirit.  2/3 of which were cut off from physical manifestation on earth with his crucifixion (the father and son).  Leaving the Holy Spirit on earth.

I'm fairly new and I can't find anything in agreement with this outside the bible (scripture seems to attest) toward a similar interpretation.  What I have found suggests a slaughter of 2/3 of the Jewish population by Rome. In my opinion this isn't in the spirit of the passage. I'm not above correction if I'm off please point me in the appropriate direction. What does anybody else think?

Zechariah 13:6-9 King James Version

> 6 And one shall say unto him, What are these wounds in thine hands?
> Then he shall answer, Those with which I was wounded in the house of
> my friends.
>
> 7 Awake, O sword, against my shepherd, and against the man that is my
> fellow, saith the Lord of hosts: smite the shepherd, and the sheep
> shall be scattered: and I will turn mine hand upon the little ones.
>
> 8 And it shall come to pass, that in all the land, saith the Lord, two
> parts therein shall be cut off and die; but the third shall be left
> therein.
>
> 9 And I will bring the third part through the fire, and will refine
> them as silver is refined, and will try them as gold is tried: they
> shall call on my name, and I will hear them: I will say, It is my
> people: and they shall say, The Lord is my God

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for joining the group and your question.  Please remember to take the tour to better understand how this site works.

Comment: This is a reasonable question but it concerns the understanding a Christian doctrine. I think it might be better on Christianity SX.

Comment: Phil, I edited your question to improve the formatting. We normally highlight biblical quotations and then hit the quotation marks icon at the top of the editing box.

Comment: Thank you everyone I apologize for my ignorance on these platforms. I appreciate the help!

Comment: I'm not sure if it should be migrated - we don't want questions directed to both Trinitarians and non-Trinitarians. Would it be fair to say that the main thrust of your question is that you see this passage as supportive of the Trinity, so you're surprised that you've never seen Trinitarians use this sort of explanation, and you'd like to know why? If that question was more explicit we could definitely migrate it to [Christianity.se] :)

Comment: In verse 9, regarding the third part that gets refined God says, "It is my people" so ... not the Holy Spirit.

Comment: This is a place where the KJV gets it a bit wrong:  the Hebrew actually reads "between your hands" in verse 6.  This is why some translators have gone with "on your chest" -- stretch out your arms and your chest is between them -- or even "on your body".

Comment: Hi, @Phil, glad to have you join. Your statement *Jesus being the earthly embodiment of the Father, Son and Holy Spirit. 2/3 of which were cut off from physical manifestation on earth with his crucifixion* will be the problem on both this site and Christianity.SE. That is not from any Biblical literal-grammatical hermeneutic nor from any known Bible-church-centered religious tradition. Are you asking if Ze 13:8 is a 1/3 reference to the three parts in Mt 28:19 and leaving the Holy Spirit as a gift to humans on earth per Jn 14:26? If so, that would be a hermeneutical question and it could stay.

Comment: There's been no response for a week. The other mod and I have discussed this and agree it is time to close it until it can be improved. It would be great to address this more, but we need to know what is being asked for either this site or [Christianity.SE](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/). If you can answer either Curious's question or my question, then edit this so we can better understand what is being asked, then click Flag and ask for a moderator to review it. Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

The reason few if any commentators see vss. 8-9 in the OP as a prophecy regarding the Holy Trinity that these verses clearly speak of the land and the people, not of God. This becomes even more clear if one continues to the next chapter, keeping in mind that there were no chapter divisions in the original:

> And it shall come to pass, that in all the land, saith the Lord, two parts therein shall be cut off and die; but the third shall be left therein. And I will bring the third part through the fire, and will refine them as silver is refined, and will try them as gold is tried: they shall call on my name, and I will hear them: I will say, It is my people: and they shall say, The Lord is my God. Behold, a day of the Lord is coming, when the spoil taken from you
> will be divided in the midst of you. For I will gather all the
> nations against Jerusalem to battle, and the city shall be taken and
> the houses plundered and the women ravished; half of the city shall go
> into exile, but the rest of the people shall not be cut off from the
> city. Then the Lord will go forth and fight against those nations as
> when he fights on a day of battle.

Conclusion: taken in context, this prophecy clearly relates to a physical battle in which Israel will suffer greatly. But in a succeeding battle, after Israel has repented, God will fight on Israel's side and restore what has been lost.

---

**Addendum**: since the OP seems to presume that this section involves a messianic prophecy, I will add that vs. 6 does not refer to the messiah, especially not if the messiah is Jesus. The KJV says the man  is wounded in the "hands" but most modern translation reject this translation, saying the wounds are on his body. More important, the preceding verses are about *false* prophets who are wounded by their own pious families - not about a messiah who is wounded by his people.

> 2 And on that day...   I will cut off the names of the idols... I will remove from the land the prophets and the unclean spirit 3 And if any one again appears as a prophet, his father and mother
> who bore him will say to him, ‘You shall not live, for you speak lies
> in the name of the Lord’; and his father and mother who bore him shall
> pierce him through when he prophesies.

It is these false prophets who will be wounded, not the messiah.

Comment: Thank you Dan!  if you don't mind I have a few questions.  The preceding passages are in reference to the crusifixtion 6-7 correct?  The second question is in reference to 2/3 shall be cut off in "all the land" not just specific to Jerusalem as the latter text.    Wouldnt this be prophetic to include the gentiles after crusifixtion and death of the son of God leaving the Holy Spirit to remain on earth after his assention?  The scripture following seems specific to 1/2 of Jerusalem not necessarily 2/3 from "all the land"  appearing more linear in presentation?  What is lost for all and Jerusale

Comment: The KJV translation is particularly amenable to the idea that this is about the crucifixion. But I suspect it is not the best translation in terms of what the original says. Check some of the [other translations](https://www.biblegateway.com/verse/en/Zechariah%2013:6) and you will see what I mean. Even accepting the KJV, Jesus was not wounded in the house of his friends. Unfortunately, this site's format does not lend itself to lengthy follow-up discussion. I'll just say that the prophecy is not entirely clear to me but I am fairly confident that it is about people, not the Trinity.

Comment: good article here weighing pros and cons as to whether the preceding verses are messianic or not. https://carm.org/king-james-onlyism/zechariah-136-and-king-james-onlyism/

Comment: That was a good read, thank you.  I will look up the rest of the passages I had in question in other translations to bring more clarity.  If it wasn't prophetic to Jesus's crucifixion then that whole theory falls flat.  I am thankful for your direction and will attempt to avoid getting tunnel vision in the future (something I was weary of when starting this process and still fell right in it).

Comment: I accidentally ended up at 3:6-9 and it was interesting since that is a plain Messianic passage.  But 13:6-9 isn't.